# UIAutomation failed to tap a key

Tags: ios, testing, automated-tests, instruments, ios-ui-automation

i use UIAutomation and instrument for my UI Tests and when i try to tap some letters, instrument return me an error:

```
Script threw an uncaught JavaScript error: target.frontMostApp().keyboard() failed to tap 'V' on line 27
```

A part of code:

```
passwordField.tap();
target.frontMostApp().keyboard().typeString("VEMO");
```

Has anyone some ideas about it?

Thank

Comment: Does adding a delay between tapping the password field and typing the string help?  The animation that shows the keyboard takes roughly 0.33 seconds to complete.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is an undocumented function that exists on the UIAKeyboard object that will help you avoid this problem.

```
var keyboard = target.frontMostApp().keyboard();
keyboard.setInterKeyDelay(seconds);
keyboard.typeString("VEMO");
```

You can push the delay up as high as you want but I found that a delay of 0.1 was enough to prevent the keyboard from failing.